# How to set size of select element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I'm trying to set size attribute of a created node with jQuery.

```
var category_selector_lvl0 = $('<select>',{
            id: 'category_selector_lvl0',
            size: 6
});
```

But the size attribute doesn't be writed... :(

```
<select id="category_selector_lvl0">
       <option value="14">...</option>
       <option value="1">...</option>
       <option value="40">...</option>
</select>
```

I expect to get something like that:

```
<select id="category_selector_lvl0" size="6">
       <option value="14">...</option>
       <option value="1">...</option>
       <option value="40">...</option>
</select>
```

I tried some variant like:

```
var category_selector_lvl0 = $('<select>',{
            id: 'category_selector_lvl0',
            size: '6'
});
```

But without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
var category_selector_lvl0 = $('<select>',{
            id: 'category_selector_lvl0'
}).attr('size',6);
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/Uq2ap/8/

Generated Html :

```
<select id="category_selector_lvl0" size="6"></select>
```

Comment: It works, thanks for your idea:)

But to my personal knowledge, I would like to know why we can't pass that attribute with parameter array...